# Biblatex print postnote in the middle of cite

Tags: biblatex

I use the postnote option to specify the page number. My citation-style however requires me to use {prenote}{name + title}[Page number]{URL} for any online source, which has a sort page numbering.
I already know that I can use the bibmacro "cite:postnote" also in the .bbx-file. But I could not figure out how to not print the postnote if it already was printed before the url.

full test sample

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,DIV=calc,headinclude=true,bibliography=totoc,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\begin{filecontents}{testing.bib}
@Online{test,
  author = {Oliver Jake},
  title = {Book about Books},
  URL = {https://example.com/},
  year = {2018},
  urlyear = {2019},
  urlmonth = {12},
  urlday = {20}
}

@Online{test1,
  author = {Harry Callum},
  title = {Testing Books},
  URL = {http://google.com/},
  year = {2017},
  urlyear = {2020},
  urlmonth = {01},
  urlday = {05}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{vwa.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{vwa.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid]

\InitializeCitationStyle{\numgdef{\cbx@resetcount}{\cbx@resetcount+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperlink}{%
  \bibhyperlink{\iffootnote{f}{t}:\cbx@resetcount:\thefield{entrykey}}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhypertarget}{%
  \bibhypertarget{\iffootnote{f}{t}:\cbx@resetcount:\thefield{entrykey}}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@resetcount}{0}
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{textcitecount}}{\value{textcitetotal}-1}}

\newtoggle{cbx:loccit}

\newbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}
\newbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{}
\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{ibidpage}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[string]{citepages}[permit]{%
  \ifcsdef{cbx@opt@citepages@#1}
    {\csuse{cbx@opt@citepages@#1}}
    {\PackageError{biblatex}
       {Invalid option 'citepages=#1'}
       {Valid values are 'permit', 'suppress', 'omit', 'separate'.}}}

\providebibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}
\providebibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{}
\providebibmacro*{cite:postnote}{}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@permit{%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@suppress{%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{pagetotal}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@omit{%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
      and
      test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
    }
      {\clearfield{pages}%
       \clearfield{pagetotal}}
      {}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@separate{%
  \providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      togl {cbx:fullcite}
      and
      test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
      and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
      and
      (
        not test {\iffieldundef{pages}}
        or
        not test {\iffieldundef{pagetotal}}
      )
    }
      {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote:pages}}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}
  \providebibmacro*{cite:postnote:pages}{%
    \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
    \bibstring{thiscite}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printfield{postnote}}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=context,ibidtracker=constrict,
  pagetracker,autocite=footnote,citepages=permit}

\newbibmacro*{cite}
{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
  {
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {
        \ifboolexpr
        {
          test {\ifciteibid}
          and
          not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
  }
  {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
}

\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote:ibidpage}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\addspace\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\onlinecite}[\mkbibfoornote]
  {\addspace\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:init}{%
  \citetrackerfalse%
  \pagetrackerfalse%
  \iffirstcitekey
    {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:count}{%
  \stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{uniquelist}}{\value{maxnames}}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{uniquelist}}{\value{textcitemaxnames}}
       {\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{\value{uniquelist}}}
       {}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{labelname}}{\value{maxnames}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{\value{textcitemaxnames}}
          {\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{\value{labelname}}}
          {}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{maxnames}}{\value{textcitemaxnames}}
          {\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{\value{maxnames}}}
          {}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\iffirstcitekey
        {}
        {\textcitedelim}%
      \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
      \usebibmacro{textcite}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite\footcite]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}%
   \gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@footcite@args{%
        (\thefield{multiprenote})(\thefield{multipostnote})}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{textcite:count}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
   \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@textcite@args{{\cbx@savedkeys}}%
      \protected@xappto\cbx@footcite@args{%
        [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}%
      \iflastcitekey
        {\protected@xappto\cbx@textcite@args{\thefield{postpunct}}%
         \protected@xappto\cbx@footcite@args{\nopunct}}
        {}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}

% textcite has nested \DeclareCiteCommand definitions for textcite and we want to use
% the normal textcite context
\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@textcite}{textcite}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@init}[3]{%
  \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
  \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
  \setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{0}%
  \def\cbx@textcite@args{#1}\def\cbx@footcite@args{#2}#3%
  \cbx@textcite@args\@empty\cbx@footcite@args\@empty}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}{\cbx@textcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}
  [\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcites\footcites]{\textcite}{}

\let\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcite@init
\pretocmd{\cbx@textcites@init}{%
  \UseNextMultiCiteHook%
  \AtNextMultiCite{%
    \renewbibmacro{multiprenote}{}%
    \renewbibmacro{multipostnote}{}}}{}{}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{vwa.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{vwa.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\textnormal{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \textnormal{\usebibmacro{url}}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}
     \newunit
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\newbibmacro*{bookdate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printlabeldateextra}
}

\newbibmacro*{fulldate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {%
            \iflabeldateisdate
            {\printfield{issue}%
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \printdateextra}
            {\printlabeldateextra}}
}%

\newbibmacro*{onlineauthor}{%
  {\printnames{author}%
  \printunit{\space}}
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
%   \usebibmacro{date+extradate}
    }

\newbibmacro*{publisher}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  }

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{onlineauthor}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  \addcolon
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
%   \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{mergedate}[true]{%
  \ifcsdef{bbx@opt@mergedate@#1}
    {\csuse{bbx@opt@mergedate@#1}}
    {\PackageError{biblatex}
       {Invalid option 'mergedate=#1'}
       {Valid values are 'maximum', 'compact', 'basic', 'minimum',\MessageBreak
        'true' (=compact), and 'false'.}}}

\providebibmacro*{date+extradate}{}
\providebibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \blx@warning{bibmacro 'date+extrayear' is deprecated.\MessageBreak
    Please use 'date+extradate'.\MessageBreak
    Using 'date+extradate' instead}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\@secondoftwo}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%

\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@true{\bbx@opt@mergedate@compact}

% merge date/issue with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@maximum{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \iflabeldateisdate
           {\printfield{issue}%
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \printdateextra}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\iflabeldateisdate}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}}}

% merge date with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@compact{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \iflabeldateisdate
           {\printdateextra}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\iflabeldateisdate}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{issue}}}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
           {}
           {\printdate}}}%
    \newunit}}

% merge year-only date with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@basic{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflabeldateisdate}
      and
      not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
    }%
  }%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
    }
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}%
    \newunit}}

% merge year-only date with year-only date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@minimum{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflabeldateisdate}
      and
      not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{extradate}}
    }%
  }%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
    }
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}%
    \newunit}}

% don't merge date/issue with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@false{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\@secondoftwo}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printfield{issue}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labeldateparts,sorting=nyt,pagetracker,mergedate}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt}

\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\defbibenvironment{shorthand}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\InitializeBibliographyStyle{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbool{bbx@inset}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

\renewbibmacro*{begrelated}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}}

\renewbibmacro*{endrelated}{%
  \usebibmacro*{bbx:savehash}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}

\newbibmacro*{labeltitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {\printfield{title}%
        \clearfield{title}}
       {\printfield[title]{shorttitle}}}
    {\printfield{label}}}

\endinput
\renewc
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=vwa,dashed=false,backref=true,natbib=true,hyperref=true,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testing.bib}

\begin{document}

This a test sentence and the following is lorem ipsum.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\footcite[S. 67]{test}\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\footcite[S. 100]{test1}\\

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help!

Currently showing:

```
Oliver Jake (2018): Book about Books. url: https://example.com/ [Aufgerufen am: 20. 12. 2019], S. 67.
```

wanted:

```
Oliver Jake (2018): Book about Books, S. 67., url: https://example.com/ [Aufgerufen am: 20. 12. 2019]
```

Comment: Don't show only snippets, make a complete example that can be used for tests (you can use biblatex-example.bib for dummy entries).

Comment: Completely unrelated to the actual question, but: (1) Do not use ```\\``` in the text to break lines. Generally, ```\\``` need only be used in tables and display math. To end a paragraph leave an empty line (or write `\par`)  inside a paragraph there (usually) should be no manual line breaks. (2) `biblatex` can add the "S." prefix itself, so you can (and should!) just write `\footcite[100]{test1}` instead of `\footcite[S. 100]{test1}`.

Comment: Also: It is officially not supported to give the URL access date in `urlyear`, `urlmonth` and `urlday`. The correct way is to give the complete date in ISO8601 `YYYY-MM-DD` format in `urldate`: `urldate = {2020-01-05},`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add some code to print the `postnote` field to the `@online` driver.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{onlineauthor}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  \addcolon
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \ifcitation
    {\iffieldpages{postnote}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}%
        \printfield{postnote}}
       {}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
%   \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

Then you will have to modify the postnote printing commands to skip the postnote when you have a fullcite of an `@online` entry.

```
\def\cbx@opt@citepages@permit{%
  \providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
          togl {cbx:fullcite}
      and test {\ifentrytype{online}}
      and test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}}
```

In full (and with some adjustments to suppress spurious white space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@Online{test,
  author  = {Oliver Jake},
  title   = {Book about Books},
  URL     = {https://example.com/},
  year    = {2018},
  urldate = {2019-12-20},
}
@Online{test1,
  author = {Harry Callum},
  title  = {Testing Books},
  URL    = {http://google.com/},
  year   = {2017},
  urdate = {2020-01-05},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{vwa.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{vwa.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid]

\InitializeCitationStyle{\numgdef{\cbx@resetcount}{\cbx@resetcount+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperlink}{%
  \bibhyperlink{\iffootnote{f}{t}:\cbx@resetcount:\thefield{entrykey}}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhypertarget}{%
  \bibhypertarget{\iffootnote{f}{t}:\cbx@resetcount:\thefield{entrykey}}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@resetcount}{0}
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{textcitecount}}{\value{textcitetotal}-1}}

\newtoggle{cbx:loccit}

\newbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}
\newbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{}
\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{ibidpage}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[string]{citepages}[permit]{%
  \ifcsdef{cbx@opt@citepages@#1}
    {\csuse{cbx@opt@citepages@#1}}
    {\PackageError{biblatex}
       {Invalid option 'citepages=#1'}
       {Valid values are 'permit', 'suppress', 'omit', 'separate'.}}}

\providebibmacro*{cite:citepages}{}
\providebibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{}
\providebibmacro*{cite:postnote}{}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@permit{%
  \providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
          togl {cbx:fullcite}
      and test {\ifentrytype{online}}
      and test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@suppress{%
  \providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{pagetotal}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifentrytype{online}}
      and test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@omit{%
  \providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
      and
      test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
    }
      {\clearfield{pages}%
       \clearfield{pagetotal}}
      {}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifentrytype{online}}
      and test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}}

\def\cbx@opt@citepages@separate{%
  \providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
    \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
    \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      togl {cbx:fullcite}
      and
      test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
      and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
      and
      (
        not test {\iffieldundef{pages}}
        or
        not test {\iffieldundef{pagetotal}}
      )
    }
      {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote:pages}}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}
  \providebibmacro*{cite:postnote:pages}{%
    \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
    \bibstring{thiscite}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printfield{postnote}}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=context,ibidtracker=constrict,
  pagetracker,autocite=footnote,citepages=permit}

\newbibmacro*{cite}
{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
  {%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {%
      \ifboolexpr
        {%
          test {\ifciteibid}
          and
          not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}%
    }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  }
  {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:postnote:ibidpage}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\onlinecite}[\mkbibfoornote]
  {\addspace\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:init}{%
  \citetrackerfalse%
  \pagetrackerfalse%
  \iffirstcitekey
    {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:count}{%
  \stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{uniquelist}}{\value{maxnames}}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{uniquelist}}{\value{textcitemaxnames}}
       {\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{\value{uniquelist}}}
       {}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{labelname}}{\value{maxnames}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{\value{textcitemaxnames}}
          {\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{\value{labelname}}}
          {}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{maxnames}}{\value{textcitemaxnames}}
          {\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{\value{maxnames}}}
          {}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\iffirstcitekey
        {}
        {\textcitedelim}%
      \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
      \usebibmacro{textcite}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite\footcite]
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}%
   \gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@footcite@args{%
        (\thefield{multiprenote})(\thefield{multipostnote})}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{textcite:count}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
   \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@textcite@args{{\cbx@savedkeys}}%
      \protected@xappto\cbx@footcite@args{%
        [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}%
      \iflastcitekey
        {\protected@xappto\cbx@textcite@args{\thefield{postpunct}}%
         \protected@xappto\cbx@footcite@args{\nopunct}}
        {}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}

% textcite has nested \DeclareCiteCommand definitions for textcite and we want to use
% the normal textcite context
\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@textcite}{textcite}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@init}[3]{%
  \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
  \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
  \setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{0}%
  \def\cbx@textcite@args{#1}\def\cbx@footcite@args{#2}#3%
  \cbx@textcite@args\@empty\cbx@footcite@args\@empty}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}{\cbx@textcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}
  [\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcites\footcites]{\textcite}{}

\let\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcite@init
\pretocmd{\cbx@textcites@init}{%
  \UseNextMultiCiteHook%
  \AtNextMultiCite{%
    \renewbibmacro{multiprenote}{}%
    \renewbibmacro{multipostnote}{}}}{}{}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{vwa.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{vwa.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \textnormal{\usebibmacro{url}}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printfield[titlecase]{title}%
     \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
     \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\newbibmacro*{bookdate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printlabeldateextra}%
}

\newbibmacro*{fulldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\iflabeldateisdate
       {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printdateextra}
       {\printlabeldateextra}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{onlineauthor}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \printunit{\space}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
%   \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
    }

\newbibmacro*{publisher}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{onlineauthor}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  \addcolon
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \ifcitation
    {\iffieldpages{postnote}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}%
        \printfield{postnote}}
       {}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
%   \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{mergedate}[true]{%
  \ifcsdef{bbx@opt@mergedate@#1}
    {\csuse{bbx@opt@mergedate@#1}}
    {\PackageError{biblatex}
       {Invalid option 'mergedate=#1'}
       {Valid values are 'maximum', 'compact', 'basic', 'minimum',\MessageBreak
        'true' (=compact), and 'false'.}}}

\providebibmacro*{date+extradate}{}
\providebibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \blx@warning{bibmacro 'date+extrayear' is deprecated.\MessageBreak
    Please use 'date+extradate'.\MessageBreak
    Using 'date+extradate' instead}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\@secondoftwo}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%

\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@true{\bbx@opt@mergedate@compact}

% merge date/issue with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@maximum{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \iflabeldateisdate
           {\printfield{issue}%
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \printdateextra}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\iflabeldateisdate}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}}}

% merge date with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@compact{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \iflabeldateisdate
           {\printdateextra}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\iflabeldateisdate}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{issue}}}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
           {}
           {\printdate}}}%
    \newunit}}

% merge year-only date with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@basic{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflabeldateisdate}
      and
      not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
    }%
  }%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
    }
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}%
    \newunit}}

% merge year-only date with year-only date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@minimum{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflabeldateisdate}
      and
      not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{extradate}}
    }%
  }%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
    }
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}%
    \newunit}}

% don't merge date/issue with date label
\def\bbx@opt@mergedate@false{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\@secondoftwo}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printfield{issue}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labeldateparts,sorting=nyt,pagetracker,mergedate}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt}

\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\defbibenvironment{shorthand}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\InitializeBibliographyStyle{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbool{bbx@inset}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

\renewbibmacro*{begrelated}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}}

\renewbibmacro*{endrelated}{%
  \usebibmacro*{bbx:savehash}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}

\newbibmacro*{labeltitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {\printfield{title}%
        \clearfield{title}}
       {\printfield[title]{shorttitle}}}
    {\printfield{label}}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=vwa,dashed=false,backref=true,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\footcite[67]{test}

Lorem ipsum.\footcite[100]{test1}

Lorem ipsum.\footcite[100]{test1}

Amet.\footcite[67]{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Oliver Jake (2018): Book about Books, S. 67. url: https://example.com/ [besucht am 20.12.2019].//Harry Callum (2017): Testing Books, S. 100. url: http://google.com/.//Ebd., S. 100.//Oliver Jake, Book about Books, S. 67.]

Comment: Working well with only numbers, but not if cite command is \footcite[\pno 100f.]{test}.

Comment: @Teichi Yes, the code explicitly checks if the `postnote` looks like a page number and only moves the code if that is the case. Don't write `\footcite[\pno 100f.]{test}` write `\footcite[100\psq]{test}`.

Comment: Of course you could also remove the test if you don't like it: There are some `\iffieldpages{postnote}`s in the code, just get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect!